# PHP: Dropdown options from database

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I am a newbie in php. I am trying to write code for displaying dropdown select from database(my_db).

I've attached the code here:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$dbuname,$dbpwd,"my_db") or die("Couldn't connect!!!". mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($con,"my_db");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select country from Country");

$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//echo $rowcount;

if($rowcount) {
    $select = '<select name="select">';
    //echo $select;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //printf ("%s \n",$row["country"]);
        //echo "<br>";
        $select.='<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.$rs['country'].'</option>';
        //echo $select;
    }
    $select .= "</select>";
    echo $select;

}
?>
```

I refer this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?696819-Populate-dropdown-menu-from-MySQL-database) for writing this code.

But, I didn't get the output. The dropdown box would be blank.

What did I make as wrong?

Please give more idea to improve my code.

Thank you in Advance!!!

Comment: Replace `$rs['country']` with `$row['country']`

Comment: what is this $rs['country']? should not it be $row['country']

Comment: Did you try any of the answers that were given already?

Comment: Sorry it is my fault. After i changed $rs['country'] to $row['country'], it is working fine. Thank you for all who answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

put php code inside html tag.

```
<select id="selectbox" name="selectbox">
<?php
//here your query
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {?>

 <option value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>"><?php echo $rs['country'];?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<select name="select">';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.

```
//db connection  
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password"); 
mysql_select_db("database"); 

//query 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){ 
$select= '<select name="select">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;
```